# tagging a page in photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Greetings

Here's what's up:

I'm working on an app where the user or a page they administrate is tagged in their own image, however, tagging a page they administrate doesn't function, I have no trouble with the user being tagged.

Here's some code:

```
$tdata = array('tag_uid' => $fb_id,'x' => 0,'y' => 0);
$datatags[] = $tdata;

$attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'tags' => $datatags
);

$attachment['image'] = '@'.realpath($image_name.);
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'POST', $attachment);
```

`$fb_id` is either the ID for the user or the page. which is grabbed using `/me/accounts` in the Graph API

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at newest facebook policies which disallow tagging photos through code, and has been removed from newer apis.

Comment: the app will simply ask for 'extended' permissions. this code works fine for users, but pages cannot be tagged using this code, they can be tagged manually afterwards, however.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation you cannot do this:

> You can specify which user to tag using two methods: in the URL path
>   as PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID, or in a URL parameter as
>   PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID. **Currently, you cannot tag a Page in a photo
>   using this API.**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/